# Different decimal symbol C#

Tags: c#

I have program that save doubles it produce to file and read the file for next run.
Problem is when it want to read file for first time in different windows, it could not manage decimal symbol in different windows, some windows use symbol like '.' and some of them use '/' as separator.
How can i handle this problem?

load section:

```
private void Load( string file )
    {
        if ( File.Exists( file ) )
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( file );
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
              //I think i should use IFormatProvider here.
            m_GamesTrained = int.Parse( line );
              //Some code here!but irrelevant to topic

            reader.Close();
        }       
    }
```

and save section:

```
private void Save( string file )
    {

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( file, false );

                m_LastGamesTrainedSave = m_GamesTrained;
                writer.WriteLine( m_GamesTrained.ToString() );

                float[] contactWeights = m_ContactNetwork.GetWeights();
                for ( int i = 0; i < contactWeights.Length; i++ )
                {
                  //I think i should use IFormatProvider here too
                    writer.WriteLine( contactWeights[i].ToString() );
                }


                writer.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Use [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3ebe5aks.aspx) with a fixed [IFormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) like [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) for writing/reading between systems. - If you don't provide a fixed IFormatProvider, it will use CurrentUICulture which is likely to be different on different systems and causes the `,` vs. `.` (not seen `/` as a decimal separator, yet) confusion.

Comment: Btw. sorry for the confusion. You have `decimal` in the title, `double` in the text and `float` in the code (why `float`?). All those value types implement [IFormattable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.iformattable.aspx), so you're able to provide a fixed IFormatProvider to all of them. - and after reading, you can give that same IFormatProvider to the [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bh4863by.aspx) method.

Comment: In windows 8.1 you can see '/' as separator. how can i use `IformatProvider` in my code?

Comment: I used open source for my project, and its not my code. but i had this problem for decimal numbers. So i don't know why he/she used `float` in code.

Comment: Have you actually read the provided links? There are examples that explain how to use it, better than I could.

Comment: Yes, and i understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Globalization;
```

For saving data:

```
number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Fore reading numbers:

```
int.Parse(number,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//you can use float instead of int
```

Comment: `CurrentCulture`, much like `CurrentUICulture` can *vary* from system to system. If you want to reliably exchange data between different systems (or even the same system with changing culture settings) it is important that writing and reading (parsing) is done with the exact same culture. That's what `InvariantCulture` was intended for. It also makes the promise to not ever(?) change. For example a culture setting that has a `.` as decimal separator might some day in the future change that to `|`. And then everything saved *before* that change could not be read correctly *after* the change.

Comment: Using `InvariantCulture`, the promise is, that there will never be such a change. So everything you save with that, you will always be able to correctly parse again later.

Comment: So should i edit this answer to this :  `int.Parse(number,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`?

Comment: Well, the important thing is that you use the exact same `IFormatProvider` (`CultureInfo`) for the `ToString` *and* the `Parse`. And `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` can be *differen* on different systems. So if you call `string exchange = doubleNumber.ToSting(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` on one system and `double.Parse(exchange, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` on a different system with a different culture setting (with a different decimal separator), you will run into the same problems.

Comment: If you use for example `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")` on both sides, you won't have those problems. Except for the very unlikely event that the US would ever change the decimal separator in their culture. With `InvariantCulture` you are as safe as possible from even that remote possibility.

Comment: Thanks man, this help me.i tried this code and get positive result.